# Normals with transparency issues?

Tags: transparency, normals

I've done a lot of digging and thought I came to a couple of conclusions but it didn't pan out.

[image: Here is my face orientation, so my normals are correct.]

When I enable show backfaces and look at the mesh from the side like this, this is what I see.

[image: Enabled backfaces]

[image: Rendered in engine (there is more because I have parts hidden in blender)]

Since this mesh in particular is using a transparent texture in engine, this is exactly how it looks, I see a bunch of triangles that look almost like an inverted face even though they are not...  If I use a texture that isn't transparent everything is fine.  Has anyone run into a problem like this?  Oddly enough I can seem to fix this one quad at a time by manually cutting in my own triangles.  What is even more odd is when I do this, sometimes it doesn't work and if I cut it again the same exact way, it does...

I've been researching this for two days and I haven't found anything.  Any help or insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: If adding triangles works, then does going into face select mode in edit mode, right clicking and selecting "Quads to tris", and then resetting the normal vectors help?

Comment: When I triangulate it becomes a mess, resetting the vectors doesn't work, if I focus on the one corner when it triangulates it, half of it is red, and half of it is dark

Comment: Hmmm... Might need to have the vectors reset to be pushed outside so they're all normalized facing the same way. If that doesn't work, would you be happy giving a link to your blend file so I can check it out?

Comment: I should probably add also that this only happens after I subdivide the mesh, the low poly mesh doesn't have this problem that I can tell.  I found a couple videos that said this would happen and to recalculate outside but that's where it ends

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that with vectors, all I know how to do is hit the buttons in the normals menu for them.  Can you have them point towards the cursor like you can do with normals?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RPvp84-JHkznaDKVGG6HHigMClsSw0yR/view?usp=sharing

Here's the blend file if you want to take a look at it.

Comment: I think there is some way to do that, but the main way to reset normal vectors outside is to open the normal menu with what I think is Ctrl+N, and to press recalculate outside. Not sure yet about why the subdivision is affecting things. Going to look over your blend file

Comment: Also quick question, what Blender version are you using? Might need to upgrade since I only have 2.9 on this laptop for some reason and the file isnt opening

Comment: This is using 4.0

Comment: While I haven't looked at the file, your normals are fine.  That's not the issue.  The issue is with alpha blend mesh sorting.  To blend alpha right, it has to divide intersecting faces and draw back to front, and doing that *just right* is really expensive-- Blender doesn't do it, and for things like this, consider alpha hashed instead of alpha blend.  For your engine, you may want to focus your questions somewhere that deals with that engine.  You should be looking for problems/solutions related to "alpha sorting".

Answer (score 0):

That is actually so confusing! I turned off show backface, and it turns blue, but once you render it, it's completely fine.

Here's what I mean.

In 3D Editor:

[image: it's blue!]

When Rendered:
[image: it's normal!]

Notes: I also triangulated the whole mesh, though I doubt that did anything. I also did a few other things that I can't remember, but here's the edited version: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DH4hkt622IBnxtourTFeeyZxVYcn7kiG/view?usp=sharing

By the way, what engine are you using and what are you trying to export the file as?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for this!  Now that I knew the right terminology I found an article about this.  Sorting elements with all my face selected seems to have done the trick at least to a good enough effect in blender.  When importing into the engine it translates and is correct.